# Comparing two JSON files objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The question is open, but I could not find any answers to it on the web. hope it's not a copy:

I have to load some data in my app from a Json file. Every 3 seconds, all objects loaded previously are deleted and then reloaded (re allocated completely). I would like the app first to check if there has been a change, and only if there has been, reload the entire data, or even better, reload just the new data. how can I check if the file has been modified? Can I for example get the date from dropbox and check the date for updated versions of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the check for specific data changes, you can store hash / checksum of the file when you read it, and before reloading it compare the checksum / hash with the stored one. No change => no reload.

Comment: one thing: what is the checksum / hash? what do I need to search on google?

Comment: If you have `openssl` you can use (I like it because it's fast) [`SHA1`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/SHA1.3ssl.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to this discussion, you can get the *metadata* for a file on Dropbox and check the *rev* field in the metadata. (Stands for revision.) So you can keep track of the *rev* in your program and only try to reload the file when it changes.

http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=48787

Beware, there is an older metadata for revision, but it is deprecated. (Also covered in the discussion.)